# How android input system knows the input event is not handled so that cause an anr?

Tags: android

I write an app with a button, when the button is clicked, the following method will be invoked:

```
    public void click(View view) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, apparently, this will cause an anr after a next input event come. I thought this click method handling the input event will not cause the finishInputEvent method in InputEventReceiver class be called, but I'm wrong, finishInputEvent is still called whether the click method returns or not. finishInputEvent method in InputEventReceiver class is like this:

```
    public final void finishInputEvent(InputEvent event, boolean handled) {
        if (event == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("event must not be null");
        }
        if (mReceiverPtr == 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event "
                    + "receiver has already been disposed.");
        } else {
            int index = mSeqMap.indexOfKey(event.getSequenceNumber());
            if (index < 0) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Attempted to finish an input event that is not in progress.");
            } else {
                int seq = mSeqMap.valueAt(index);
                mSeqMap.removeAt(index);
                nativeFinishInputEvent(mReceiverPtr, seq, handled);
            }
        }
        event.recycleIfNeededAfterDispatch();
    }
```

I thought nativeFinishInputEvent will remove one item in queue in input system so that anr will not be caused, but now that nativeFinishInputEvent still be called, why will anr still be caused? how input system konw the input event is not handled?

Answer (score 0):

All Android UI events are handled by a single thread for a given application. By putting that thread to sleep, you are preventing the thread from handling further events, and the system detects that there are events in the queue that are not being handled, hence the ANR. As a rule, you should *never* sleep in the UI thread.

Comment: I certainly know that, I just want to know how the input system know the input events not handled while finishInputEvent is still called.

Comment: How do you know it's called?

Comment: Maybe I should add some log in android input system.

Comment: Well, if you debugged it, you would have been able to see from the stack trace where it was being called from. Was it called in response to the button click, or some other event?